# Test: How to estimate a plausible confidence interval while only knowing a ratio and p-value

Tags: confidence-interval

I´m not sure if it´s allowed to ask specific test questions but here I go:

Right now I´m studying old test questions in statistics. I have approached a type of questions that I have no idea how to solve. I will copy one of the questions below and mark the correct answer. This is all information available for the questions. Please help me.

1. In a paper in The New England Journal of Medicine the mortality in obese patient that either underwent bariatric surgery (surgery group) or received conventional treatment (matched control group) was compared. The paper reported the unadjusted overall hazard ratio to be 0.76 in the surgery group (p-value = 0.04), as compared with the control group. This means that:

A.  A plausible 99% confidence interval for the hazard ratio is 0.69 to 0.89.
B.  A plausible 95% confidence interval for the hazard ratio is 1.0 to 1.09
**C.    A plausible 95% confidence interval for the hazard ratio is 0.59 to 0.99.**
D.  A plausible 99% confidence interval for the hazard ratio is 0.59 to 0.99.
E.  A plausible 95% confidence interval for the hazard ratio is 0.59 to 1.09.

Edit: I understand that the hazard ratio should be included in the interval but apart from that, I'm lost.

Edit 2: Is this reasoning correct: Since the p-value is 0.04, a 95% of the hazard ratio should not include 1 since that would mean no difference (1-0.95=0.05>0.04). However, a CI of 99% should include 1 since 1-0.99=0.01<0.04.
And of course, the hazard ratio should always be included in the interval.

Comment: I suspect your logic in Edit 2 is correct.